# STR_TO_DATE returns future dates for two-digit years

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a SQL table with dates in the format `12/9/66` (UK date format, dd/mm/yy). When I use:

```
UPDATE players SET dateOfBirth = STR_TO_DATE('12/9/66','%d/%m/%y')
```

It sets the date as `2066-09-12`.

Obviously I want it to be `1966-09-12`. How do I get the correct date?

Comment: How is it supposed to know that you meant 1966 and not 2066?

Comment: By the way, where is the date coming from?

Comment: Is it too late to just fix the column type? I don't know the reason but there're a lot of questions here regarding dates stored as plain text. It's funny because people seem to be spending a lot of time trying to solve a self-inflicted problem.

Comment: As you see, this date format can be interpreted differently...maybe you should consider changing the format in the table, if possible.

Comment: @SalmanA Because, I guess, all the current dates are in the past. The data comes from an input where people type in their birthdate. It's an archaic system that would be too hard to change - people are prompted to type in dd/mm/yy. Obviously a date of birth of someone who exists cannot be in the future!

Comment: Ahh.  The old `obviously I want it` thing. Pro tip: when you catch yourself thinking `obviously` when designing software, beware! We've all been there.

Comment: @O.Jones Yep - sadly I 'inherited' the backend (SQL) from a frontend written two decades ago :(

Comment: Ahh Y2k Hapy paydays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if `STR_TO_DATE` resulted in a future date ([why](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/two-digit-years.html)) then subtract 100 years:

```
UPDATE players
SET dateOfBirth = STR_TO_DATE('12/9/66','%d/%m/%y') - INTERVAL (
    CASE WHEN STR_TO_DATE('12/9/66','%d/%m/%y') <= CURRENT_DATE THEN 0 ELSE 100 END
) YEAR
```

Comment: When asked to convert a two-digit year to a four-digit year, MySQL applies a cutoff.  Any value between '70' and '99' is interpreted as a 20th-century date (`1970`) and the rest as 21st-century dates (`2066`).  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/two-digit-years.html

Comment: @O.Jones yes I could not find the behavior in the docs, thanks for pointing.